# XQuery Simple Recursive Query child to top parent in XML

Tags: xml, recursion, xquery, parent-child, hierarchy

> Input xml

```
<req>
  <family>
    <person>
      <id>id1</id>
      <name>name1</name>
      <mother>mother1</mother>
      <age>age1</age>
    </person>
    <person>
      <id>id2</id>
      <name>name2</name>
      <mother>mother2</mother>
      <age>age2</age>
    </person>
    <person>
      <id>id4</id>
      <name>mother3</name>
      <mother>mother4</mother>
    </person>
    <person>
      <id>id3</id>
      <name>mother2</name>
      <mother>mother3</mother>
      <age>age3</age>
    </person>
  </family>
</req>
```

> Could you please help me how to get the top parrent 'person' with existing element 'age' for every 'req/family/person'?
>
> My follow xquery

```
declare function local:recons($family as element(*), $person as element(*))
    as element(*) {
    let $parrent := for $p in $family/person
    where $p/name=$person/mother
    return local:recons($family,$p)
    return
    <person>
    {$person/*}
    <parrent>{$parrent}</parrent>
    </person>
};

declare function xf:MyTest($inputXML as element(*))
    as element(*) {
       <res>
       <family>
       {
       for $person in $inputXML/family/person
       return local:recons($inputXML/family,$person)
       }
       </family>
       </res>
};

declare variable $inputXML as element(*) external;

xf:MyTest($inputXML)
```

> Expected result

```
<res>
  <family>
    ...
    <person>
      <id>id2</id>
      <name>name2</name>
      <mother>mother2</mother>
      <age>age2</age>
      <parrent>
        <person>
          <id>id3</id>
          <name>mother2</name>
          <mother>mother3</mother>
          <age>age3</age>
          <parrent/>
        </person>
      </parrent>
    </person>
    ...
  </family>
</res>
```

> Actual result

```
<res>
  <family>
    ...
    <person>
      <id>id2</id>
      <name>name2</name>
      <mother>mother2</mother>
      <age>age2</age>
      <parrent>
        <person>
          <id>id3</id>
          <name>mother2</name>
          <mother>mother3</mother>
          <age>age3</age>
          <parrent>
            <person>
              <id>id4</id>
              <name>mother3</name>
              <mother>mother4</mother>
              <parrent/>
            </person>
          </parrent>
        </person>
      </parrent>
    </person>
    ...
  </family>
</res>
```

> I tried use ancestor and xpath like '$parrent//person[fn:exists(age)]', unsuccessful.
>   I tried use ancestor and xpath like '$parrent//person[fn:exists(age)]', unsuccessful.

Comment: I am not sure I have grasped the problem about where `age` is relevant and you have not spelled out the complete result. Does the result at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcox/3 represent the one you want? The implementation approach I have used there is a bit different as the recursive function simply returns the existing element from the input instead of creating new ones but as you only want the last result in the recursive call I think it is easier doing a comparison on the result later on.

Comment: Mads, thank you for feedback.

I tried to do this predicate, this solution helps well to find all parrents with existing 'age' for person.
But I want find top/last parrent with existing 'age' for person.

Expected result
res/family/person
   | top(last) parrent only

Actual result
res/family/person
   | first parrent
      | second parrent
        ...
           | top(last) parrent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the `where` clause your `local:recons()` to ensure that you are only selecting the `$parrent` (shouldn't that element and variable be spelled parent?) if it has an `age` and it's `name` matches the `$person/mother`

You could do that easily with a predicate filter:

```
where $p[age]/name = $person/mother
```

Applied to the function:

```
declare function local:recons($family as element(*), $person as element(*))
    as element(*) {
    let $parrent := for $p in $family/person
      where $p[age]/name = $person/mother
      return local:recons($family,$p)
    return
      <person>
        {$person/*}
        <parrent>{$parrent}</parrent>
      </person>
};
```